# How to wrap Iterator value into simple java class

Tags: spring, spring-data-neo4j-4

I am new in java .I want to wrap the value of result in simple java class.

```
Iterator<Map<String,Object>> result=template.query(cypher,params);
```

Any Help will be Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the template.query then you can either have it mapped to a domain entity or to the Map (and then you build the POJO yourself).

Otherwise, you can use a `@Query` in a repository and map it to a query result class.
For example

```
 @Query("MATCH (user:User) WHERE user.gender={0} RETURN user.name AS UserName, user.gender AS UserGender, user.account as UserAccount, user.deposits as UserDeposits")
 Iterable<RichUserQueryResult> findUsersByGender(Gender gender);

@QueryResult
public class RichUserQueryResult {

    private Gender userGender; 
    private String userName;
    private BigInteger userAccount;
    private BigDecimal[] userDeposits;

    public Gender getUserGender() {
        return userGender;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public BigInteger getUserAccount() {
        return userAccount;
    }

    public BigDecimal[] getUserDeposits() {
        return userDeposits;
    }
}
```

Comment: List<AdminSearchMapResult>list=new ArrayList<AdminSearchMapResult>();
  /* for(Map<String,Object>map:result){ 
    AdminSearchMapResult adminSearchMapResult=null;
    for(Map.Entry<String,Object>entry:map.entrySet()){
     String key=entry.getKey();
     Object value=entry.getValue();
     System.out.println(key+"="+value);
    list.add(adminSearchMapResult); But it returns Null  value.AdminSearchMapResult is my pojo class.i am using NEO4JTEMPLATE instance to excute the query.

Comment: Please check if your query really returns data